# How do I create a custom IntelliJ warning/error for import statements?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, replace, structural-search

I want to add a custom warning/error to IntelliJ that triggers if my Java project contains imports to a certain package.

I have looked into [Search Templates/Replace Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html#to_search_structurally), but whenever I try to type code with an "import", it gives me an "Unexpected Token" error and refuses to be created.

This is fine:

[image: "class MyCLass {}" causes no errors, and Ok button is selectable]

This is not:

[image: "import System.out; class MyClass {}" causes an "Unexpected token" popup, and Ok button is greyed out]

I also can't find examples of search templates that match on import statements. The closest thing I can find is an example in the above link where a "use static imports" checkbox is available that will make the replacement's output contain a static import.

Do search templates just not support matching on import statements for some reason, and if so why? Is there another way to do what I want to do?

Thanks in advance.

My IntelliJ version is 2022.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "illegal package dependencies" inspection is what you are looking for. It can be found under "Settings/Editor/Inspections/JVM languages/Illegal package dependencies". You can create a custom scope for all the dependencies that you don't want in your project and apply them to the predefined "All" scope.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eztTO.png)

Comment: Yes, this solution worked. Having an "All" scope, though, also creates the custom errors inside the package in question (it is inside my project). I had to create another scope that was everything except the undesired package to apply the rule to.

Answer (score 2):

Structural search for imports/packages is not supported yet - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-285199 .

As a workaround you can try using the following template:

```
<searchConfiguration name="Unnamed" text="$Type$" recursive="true" type="JAVA" pattern_context="default" search_injected="false">
  <constraint name="__context__" within="" contains="" />
  <constraint name="Type" regexp="javafx\..*" within="" contains="" />
</searchConfiguration>
```

Use the `Import Template from Clipboard` action under the tool button in the Structural Search dialog:

[image]